# Convert Plain String to JSON?

Tags: string, json

I need to convert a string to JSON (in javascript). I have a plain string with correctly formatted JSON in it, like this:

```
var convert = '{"name":nick,"age":19}';
```

I need to convert it to just the json (e.g., minus the '' quotes). I have done some testing and found this to be the reason I'm having problems. There must be a way to convert it on the fly, right?

Help very much appreciated,

Nick

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Should be `"name":"nick"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JSON library; nearly all modern browsers have a native one available to them, however, to ensure compatibility with IE7 and below you will need to pull in [Douglas Crockford's JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Once you have a JSON library, just issue:

`var result = JSON.parse('{"name":nick,"age":19}');`

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(convert)
```

[Crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) will give you JSON.parse for browsers that don't already have it (modern browsers have it natively).

Comment: Heh, I think we answered that one at the same time ;)